# Add Time into Date Time

Tags: c#

I would like to add time in current DateTime for ex.: I've date

> 12/**28**/2015 11:30:00

now in this i would like to add Time

> 02:30:00

in output:

> 12/**29**/2015 02:30

This far I've done below.

```
DateTime dFrom;
        DateTime dTo;
        string sDateFrom = "1:00:00 PM";
        string sDateTo = "1:00:00 AM";


        if (DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, out dFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, out dTo))
        {
            if (dTo < dFrom)
            {
                dTo = dTo.AddDays(1);
            }

            TimeSpan ts = dTo - dFrom;
        }

        return new DateTime();
```

how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into this at all? Do you have any code of any attempts?

Comment: You will never get this result. Adding 2:30 to 11:30 will never end up with 2:30. That's changing.

Comment: If you want to add ? Then remove the old one and add it..!!!

Comment: @rajeeshmenoth : it'll end me up with the same date. which I don't want.

Comment: Well, it is because DateTime.AddTime methods returns new DateTime and does not edit the current value.

Comment: @DovydasSopa: I don't think so, there is any function available named as DateTime.AddTime

Comment: I mean when you use Add on DateTime object. Add, AddDays, AddHours, etc.

Comment: @DovydasSopa: yes, right said.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my existing logic works like charm, it's working after some tweaks.

```
private static DateTime stringToCreateDate(DateTime dFrom, string sDateTo = "2:30:00")
    {
        DateTime dTo = new DateTime();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, out dTo))
        {
            if (dTo < dFrom)
            {
                dTo = dTo.AddDays(1);
            }

            TimeSpan ts = dTo - dFrom;
        }

        return dTo;
    }
```

Comment: Why at the hell you would need line like DateTime.TryParse(dFrom.ToString(), out dFrom) when dFrom is DateTime type?

Comment: i am updating my logic by removing such checks.

Comment: No offence, but your answer really does not make any sence.. Second if is Always true as well.. And you do not use ts anywhere as well..

Comment: i would welcome, if you have some better approach, although my object is fulfilled by this.

Comment: I would, but I don't really understand what are you trying to do.